# Not able to set Status of imported products to "Active" in Dynamics 365 sales

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365-sales

I am trying to import product table data using Azure data factory to Dynamics 365 sales and it is being imported successfully. However all the products are in draft state, even though I had set the statecode  (Status) value to 0 as in the documentation, 0 is supposed to be the value for Active.

Comment: Do you have follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update both "statecode" and "statuscode" with valid values as they are related to each other, maybe "statuscode" holds non valid value that prevents you from updating the "statecode.

check the below URL for more info:
https://powerobjects.com/2020/03/11/how-to-programmatically-set-the-status-code-field-of-a-dynamic-entity/

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM OOB Product entity is little different. You have to publish the created products in draft by default.

You can change the system wide setting though.

> [image]